# The object attached to the player does not rotate to the mouse when the player moves

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the player moves, the object attached to it does not rotate to the mouse -
[how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHrEu.gif)

The object is attached in [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwD44.png).

Player have the dynamic body type, turret - kinematic

Rotation code:

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class scrTurrMg : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public Rigidbody2D rb;
     public Camera cam;

     Vector2 mousePos;

     void Update()
     {
         mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

         Vector2 lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
         float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
         rb.rotation = angle;
     }

     void FixedUpdate()
     {

     }
 }
```

Comment: include your code for moving the thing

Comment: It seems to be doing what you have there. You're only moving the turrent not the player guessing form the script name.

Comment: [Moving code](https://i.imgur.com/bkUaveC.png)

This is a code of player, not turret

Comment: And rotation code is a code of turret (pTurrMg)